# How can I disable cloud-init?

Tags: cloud-init

I have a fully-configured instance and an image from that for an autoscaling group. When autoscaling new instances from this image, it calls cloud-init. cloud-init changes the hostname and breaks fstab.

I want to prevent cloud-init from starting on instance launch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In systems that use systemd and have a current (17.0+) version of cloud-init, [upstream documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html) describes the process for disabling cloud-init with either of the following:

- `touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`
- add `cloud-init=disabled` to the kernel command line.

For older versions of cloud-init (0.7.X) the following information  might be useful.

You can disable cloud-init's modification of /etc/fstab in one of 2 ways.

a.) by providing cloud-config that overrides the default 'mounts' entries and disables them.

```
mounts:
 - [ephemeral0, null]
 - [swap, null]
```

b.) by disabling the `mounts` module from running.  This is done by removing it from the 'cloud_config_modules' list that you'll see in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`.

With regard to hostname, you can also control that also. If you just want to stop cloud-init from modifying /etc/hostname, then:

```
preserve_hostname: true
```

Also interesting to you might be `manage_etc_hosts`.

Both of these are documented in [doc/examples/cloud-config.txt](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/examples/cloud-config.txt) (and installed in `/usr/share/doc/cloud-init/examples`)

I'm interested in knowing how cloud-init is breaking /etc/fstab, though.  Please file a bug using `ubuntu-bug cloud-init` from inside your instance, and describe what it is doing that you think is wrong.

Comment: I do not think this is actually a bug. cloud-init adds swap and ephemeral to /etc/fstab already there. As a result ephemeral mounts to 2 points: /cache and /mnt. Is it safe?

Comment: @homm depends on what you mean by "safe." I don't see anything /dangerous/ about it.

Comment: @smoser By default, it's mounting just a single volume. I'm provisioning with Chef and don't want to automate umount, so for me cloud-init is "breaking" fstab.

Comment: Note that you need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init` after making changes.

Comment: Weird behaviour. With Ubuntu 18.04.2, it looks like the file `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled` doesn't matter and only the `dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init` with data source `None` (`Failsafe datasource`) is needed. This contradicts the documentation of cloud-init.

Comment: And now it looks like it is ok. I don't know what happened so my previous comment should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Maybe the "Data Sources" stuff has nothing to do with it, I could have left them as is, and the important thing to do was just to reconfigure things to let it take `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`into account. Maybe that's what @xofer implied in his comment.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 20.04, these steps worked for me to disable and remove cloud-init:

Run this command to disable:

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

Reboot machine.

Run these commands to remove:

```
sudo apt-get purge cloud-init
sudo rm -rf /etc/cloud/; sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/
```

Comment: touching the `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled` file alone worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.7

Comment: Yes that will disable it, but not remove. The following commands also remove it.