# Disable or hide cloud-init chatter on the login prompt

Tags: server, cloud-init

I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 and when I get to the login prompt, I see a lot of messages from `cloud-init` writing over that prompt.

Is there a way to disable that or hide it or redirect it to another TTY?

I've tried creating a service that waits for `cloud-init.target`, but that doesn't work.

Uninstalling cloud-init works, but I'd prefer keeping it.

The messages that I want to hide look like this:

```
[  26.488167] cloud-init[768]: Cloud-init v. 20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 06 Nov 2020 17:00:08 +0000. Up 26.39 seconds.
[  28.318996] cloud-init[768]: Cloud-init v. 20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 06 Nov 2020 17:00:10 +0000. Up 28.21 seconds.
[  28.319963] cloud-init[768]: Cloud-init v. 20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 finished at Fri, 06 Nov 2020 17:00:10 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNone Up 28.31 seconds.
[  28.321070] cloud-init[768]: 2020-11-06 17:00:10,815 - cc_final_message.py[WARNING]: Used fallback datasource
```

They show up all mixed in with the login prompt...

Comment: This may be a duplicate. I've added the steps that worked for me in this post >>> [How can I disable cloud-init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405442/how-can-i-disable-cloud-init)

Comment: @ArturMeinild I'd prefer to disable the output only, or hide it

Comment: Right. I experience this with some other logs messages as well. I'm not sure if this can be controlled.