# cloud-init schema.py Invalid cloud-config provided

Tags: server, upgrade, 22.04, do-release-upgrade, cloud-init

Upon an attempted `do-release-upgrade` from Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 to 22.04, the installation ran, and now upon reboot, it is stopping with this error:

`cloud-init: schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided: Please run 'sudo cloud-init schema --system' to see the schema errors.`

It drops to a root prompt.

Running `cloud-init schema --system` gives:
`Error: Cloud config schema errors: users.0: {'gecos': 'User', 'groups': ['adm', 'cdrom', 'dip', 'plugdev', 'lxd', 'sudo'], 'lock_passwd': False, 'name': 'user', 'passwd' '<some hash>', 'shell': '/bin/bash'} is not valid under any of the given schemas`

(where `User`/`user` is the name of my user account)
At this point there seems to be no way to proceed, now even attempting to boot with the previous kernel gives an instant kernel panic.

I am not trying to do any sort of cloud configuration. This is a single standalone server, so I have no idea what cloud instance is is trying to initialise.

Is there a way to bypass this? Or am I supposed to be creating a cloud of one machine?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after I post the question, I get matches for the solution. One such is [here] ([How can I disable cloud-init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405442/how-can-i-disable-cloud-init)), which gives a solution of creating a blank file `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`.  That appeared to work.  Getting rid of some extraneous entries that I had in `/etc/fstab` for drives I've moved out of that server also helped.