# Remove all server software from Ubuntu

Tags: server, 22.04

How i can remove all softwares of Ubuntu server and make it lock like Ubuntu Desktop without GUI? to make boot faster.

Comment: Never understood the obsession with fast boot times (I boot my computer once a day in the morning and shut it down in the evening. But anyway. Without providing the output of `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame` nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I thought the whole point of a server was to leave it up 24/7  My 20.04 and 22.04 DE instances don't have a problem with reboot times.

Comment: I want use ubuntu server as ubuntu desktop but don't need any server softwares.
Make somthing like new distro from ubuntu

Comment: When I removed the cloud-init package, the boot time became faster.

Comment: removing software doesn't make that much of a difference. you are practically begging the O.S to fail. Plus you are using linux server software, which don't have any advanced graphics at all.

Comment: You can install practically any desktop environment on top of Ubuntu server, so this question may not be as silly at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're willing to experiment with your system, and don't mind reinstalling (I take those two as prerequisites for your question), you could remove the `ubuntu-server` metapackage for starters:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-server
```

This will remove a bunch of [server-related tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-server), and their dependencies *(I've removed a bunch of those myself on my own server)*. If you need any of the tools afterward, you can then install them manually.

You're also right that removing `cloud-init` will help - please see this [existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290180/1066942).

I'm not sure this will affect your bootup time that much, but I believe it is the most precise answer to your question.